# Change private member of class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Access and change value of private class member:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class hack_Me
{
private:
    size_t age;
public:
    size_t getAge() const
    {
        return this->age;
    }

    explicit hack_Me(size_t age):age(age) {  }

};

void change_age(hack_Me* h)
{
    *((int*)h) = 100;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    hack_Me h(12);
    printf("%d \n", h.getAge());
    change_age(&h);
    printf("%d \n", h.getAge());

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

It prints 100 after 12.

It works on MSVC 14.

Is this behavior undefined and/or compiler dependent?

**UPDATE**: Does StackOverflow give you points for downvotes?

Comment: c has not class, please remove the c tag

Comment: Something like this is waiting for bugs because the casting completely skips any compiler checks. Why not `void change_age(hack_Me* h){ *h = hack_Me( 100 ); }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this behavior undefined and/or compiler dependent?

Using `int*` to access a variable of type `size_t` is bad regardless of whether the variable is inside a class or it is by itself.

If you use

```
*(reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(h)) = 100;
```

It is not undefined behavior and it is not compiler dependent. I suspect, it won't be any different if you use:

```
*((size_t*)h) = 100;
```

Your class meets the requirements of a *standard-layout* `struct`.

From the C++11 Standard:

> **9 Classes**
>
> ...
>
> 7 A standard-layout class is a class that:
>
> — has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
>
> — has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
>
> — has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members,
>
> — has no non-standard-layout base classes,
>
> — either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
>
> — has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.
>
> 8 A *standard-layout struct* is a standard-layout class defined with the *class-key* `struct` or the *class-key* `class`.

For *standard-layout* `struct`s, the pointer to an object can be aliased to the pointer to the first member variable.

From the C++11 Standard:

> **9.2 Class members**
>
> ...
>
> 20 A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a `reinterpret_cast`, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa. *[ Note:*
>   There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct object, but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment. — *end note* ]

Comment: Thank you, for comprehensive answer.

Comment: casting from `size_t` to `int` complicates matters

Comment: @sp2danny, Keey eyes. I overlooked the fact that the member variable of the class is of type `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the hack_Me you have `size_t age;` which may be smaller than int (e.g. under 8-bit architecture it might be that sizeof(size_t) == 1 and sizeof(int) == 2). If your compiler doesn't generate padding at an end of hack_Me, it may happen that the whole hack_Me is smaller than int and thus the `*((int*)h) = 100;` might overwrite more memory than only the first member of hack_Me. Change the hack to `*((size_t*)h) = 100;` and it will be probably OK (see other answers).